# Placing PSD image in Indesign with a transparent background

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, transparency

I'm a novice Photoshop user... obviously... I've created a wine glass ring image using a brush, on a transparent background in Photoshop.  I saved this file as a PSD.  When I try to place this image in InDesign, even with the transparency option checked, it still appears with a white background.  Do I need to convert the layer/image to something else?  Thanks!

Comment: Need to use PDF or TIF

Comment: .psd should be fine, provided the .psd has a transparent background. Make certain you aren't applying a color fill to the image frame in Indesign.

Answer (score 2):

This should work. When you create a new PSD file, select 'Transparent' in the 'Background Contents' field in the new file dialog box. Then save as a psd.

Also, in InDesign, are you copying and pasting it from Photoshop? That would create a background color. Within InDesign you would need to 'Place' (File > Place) the psd file in the InDesign file.